# Cannot use regexner.mapping to define custom ner in CoreNLPServer

Tags: stanford-nlp

When I used CoreNLP command like

```
java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP \
-regexner.mapping jg-regexner.txt -annotators \
tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner -outputFormat json
```

The jg-regexner.txt is like `something to be matched\tcustom_ner`.

It was OK and my custom ner would show in the result.

However, when I tried to start a server using the command:

```
java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer \
-regexner.mapping jg-regexner.txt
```

Everything was OK but the custom regexner defined in jg-regexner.txt didn't work.

So I wonder whether `regexner.mapping` is invalid in StanfordCoreNLPServer and if so, how can I define custom regexner patterns?

I also tried tokensRegex, but failed. Maybe because I don't know how to set the pattern parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

Just add this property in the request instead of in the startup command

`http://url/?properties={"annotators":...,"regexner.mapping":"jg-regexner.txt"}`

But I don't think it a good idea...